# Trying to vertically align two floated divs in a container div

Tags: css, html, css-float, vertical-alignment

I'm attempting to float two divs next to each other below a headline. I have tried inline-block, but the only luck I have had is making the container div display: table, and child divs as display: table-cell. I am able to align the two divs using this method, but now I have a large margin or extra padding above the "table cells." Any solution to remove extra margin/padding between the headline and child divs?

If there is a solution to not using display: table and display: table-cell, I would greatly appreciate as I only defaulted to this, because I was unable to get the floats or inline-block to vertically align with each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonniebauer/GRS2k/

**HTML**

```
<div id="owner_headline">
   <h3>
      Owner/Officer Information
   </h3>
   <p>
      Second Owner/Officer (optional)
   </p>
</div>
<div id="owner_info">
   <div id="owner_info1">
      <label for="owner_name">
      Name
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="owner_name" placeholder="Name"/>
      <label for="home_address">
      Home Address
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="home_address" placeholder="Address"/>
      <label for="owner_city">
      City
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="owner_city" placeholder="City"/>
      <label for="owner_state">
      State
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="owner_state" placeholder="State"/>
      <label for="owner_zip">
      Zip
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="owner_zip" placeholder="Zip"/>
      <label for="owner_phone">
      Phone
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="owner_phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
      <label for="ownership">
      Ownership
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="ownership" placeholder="Percentage"/>
      <label>
      %
      </label>
      <label for="ssn">
      SSN
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="ssn" placeholder="XXX-XX-XXXX">
   </div>
   <div id="owner_info2">
      <label for="owner_name2">
      Name
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="owner_name2" placeholder="Name"/>
      <label for="home_address2">
      Home Address
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="home_address2" placeholder="Address"/>
      <label for="owner_city2">
      City
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="owner_city2" placeholder="City"/>
      <label for="owner_state2">
      State
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="owner_state2" placeholder="State"/>
      <label for="owner_zip2">
      Zip
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="owner_zip2" placeholder="Zip"/>
      <label for="owner_phone2">
      Phone
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="owner_phone2" placeholder="Phone"/>
      <label for="ownership2">
      Ownership
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="ownership2" placeholder="Percentage"/>
      <label>
      %
      </label>
      <label for="ssn">
      SSN
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="ssn2" placeholder="XXX-XX-XXXX">
   </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
#owner_headline {
    background-color: #000B84;
}

    #owner_headline h3 {
        background-color: #000B84;
        padding-left: 7rem;
        padding-top: .5rem;
        padding-bottom: .5rem;
        font-family: "Bank Gothic", serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        display: inline-block;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    #owner_headline p {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        float: right;
        padding-right: .1rem;
        padding-top: .25rem;
        margin-right: 1rem;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

#owner_info {
    width: 912px;
    display: table;
}

#owner_info1 {
    width: 446px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

#owner_info2 {
    display: table-cell;
}

    #owner_info1 label,
    #owner_info2 label {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #owner_info1 input,
    #owner_info2 input {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

#owner_info2 {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    width: 446px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}

    #owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(1),
    #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(1) {
        width: 400px;
    }

    #owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(2),
    #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(2) {
        width: 344px;
    }

    #owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(3),
    #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(3) {
        width: 169px;
    }

    #owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(4),
    #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(4) {
        width: 184px;
    }

    #owner_info1 label:nth-of-type(4),
    #owner_info1 label:nth-of-type(6),
    #owner_info1 label:nth-of-type(9),
    #owner_info2 label:nth-of-type(4),
    #owner_info2 label:nth-of-type(6),
    #owner_info2 label:nth-of-type(9) {
        margin-left: 1rem;
    }

    #owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(5),
    #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(5) {
        width: 173px;
    }

    #owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(6),
    #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(6) {
        width: 176px;
    }

    #owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(7),
    #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(7) {
        width: 108px;
    }

    #owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(8),
    #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(8) {
        width: 190px;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS center vertically in 2 floated divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898230/css-center-vertically-in-2-floated-divs)

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking. Could you tell me what the problem is? So I can help you.

Comment: The space is caused by the paragraph in your headline being pushed down due to lack of space. Make your headline as wide as the table.

Comment: The problem is when I tried to float the divs next to each other, they were not vertically aligned...and the "right side" div was not parallel with the left div. I have to use to table to get the two to be vertically aligned, but then I have a margin/padding issue.

Comment: where is the margin/padding issue? wich element

Comment: I resolved the issue. The problem was my float: right subheading in my headline wasn't showing up properly, which caused extra space below the headline, and thus causing the right side div to not sit parallel with the left side div.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Html:

```
    <div id="owner_headline">
    <div>
        <h3> Owner/Officer Information </h3>
        <p>
            Second Owner/Officer (optional)
        </p>
    </div>
    <span style="clear:both;"></span>
    <div id="owner_info1">
        <label for="owner_name"> Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="owner_name" placeholder="Name"/>
        <label for="home_address"> Home Address </label>
        <input type="text" id="home_address" placeholder="Address"/>
        <label for="owner_city"> City </label>
        <input type="text" id="owner_city" placeholder="City"/>
        <label for="owner_state"> State </label>
        <input type="text" id="owner_state" placeholder="State"/>
        <label for="owner_zip"> Zip </label>
        <input type="text" id="owner_zip" placeholder="Zip"/>
        <label for="owner_phone"> Phone </label>
        <input type="text" id="owner_phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
        <label for="ownership"> Ownership </label>
        <input type="text" id="ownership" placeholder="Percentage"/>
        <label> % </label>
        <label for="ssn"> SSN </label>
        <input type="text" id="ssn" placeholder="XXX-XX-XXXX">
    </div>

    <span style="clear:both;"></span>

    <div id="owner_info2">
        <label for="owner_name2"> Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="owner_name2" placeholder="Name"/>
        <label for="home_address2"> Home Address </label>
        <input type="text" id="home_address2" placeholder="Address"/>
        <label for="owner_city2"> City </label>
        <input type="text" id="owner_city2" placeholder="City"/>
        <label for="owner_state2"> State </label>
        <input type="text" id="owner_state2" placeholder="State"/>
        <label for="owner_zip2"> Zip </label>
        <input type="text" id="owner_zip2" placeholder="Zip"/>
        <label for="owner_phone2"> Phone </label>
        <input type="text" id="owner_phone2" placeholder="Phone"/>
        <label for="ownership2"> Ownership </label>
        <input type="text" id="ownership2" placeholder="Percentage"/>
        <label> % </label>
        <label for="ssn"> SSN </label>
        <input type="text" id="ssn2" placeholder="XXX-XX-XXXX">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is css:

```
body {
    width: 912px;
}
#owner_headline {
    background-color: #000B84;
}

#owner_headline h3 {
    margin: 0 80px;
    font-family: "Bank Gothic", serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#owner_headline p {
    margin: 0 65px;
    font-family: "Bank Gothic", serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#owner_info {
    width: 912px;
    display: table;
}

#owner_info1 {
    width: 446px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

#owner_info2 {
    display: table-cell;
}

#owner_info1 label, #owner_info2 label {
    font-size: 14px;
}

#owner_info1 input, #owner_info2 input {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#owner_info2 {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    width: 446px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}

#owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(1), #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(1) {
    width: 400px;
}

#owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(2), #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 344px;
}

#owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(3), #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 169px;
}

#owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(4), #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(4) {
    width: 184px;
}

#owner_info1 label:nth-of-type(4), #owner_info1 label:nth-of-type(6), #owner_info1 label:nth-of-type(9), #owner_info2 label:nth-of-type(4), #owner_info2 label:nth-of-type(6), #owner_info2 label:nth-of-type(9) {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

#owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(5), #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(5) {
    width: 173px;
}

#owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(6), #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(6) {
    width: 176px;
}

#owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(7), #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(7) {
    width: 108px;
}

#owner_info1 input:nth-of-type(8), #owner_info2 input:nth-of-type(8) {
    width: 190px;
}
```